# Is it possible to refer a local class for custom tile map on android?

Tags: java, android

I need to link a local java class which has my custom tile server path declared instead of referring TileSourceFactory.java through OSM jar files or via online.

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

[LINK] https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#main-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should be easy (I don`t have a practice with online source yet)

```
XYTileSource tileSource = 
new XYTileSource("Name of Your map", MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL,   MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL,
            256, ".png", new String[]{your server urls});
map.setTileSource(tilesSource);
```

Comment: Try go up to absttract classpublic class XYTileSource extends OnlineTileSourceBase

Comment: Try go up from XYTileSource to parent abstract class OnlineTileSourceBase and look for different implementation for several online sources for method "public abstract String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile)"; it just advise I`m not familiar with that